# JBoss 5 Backward compatibility with Java 6

Tags: java, jboss5.x

I just need clarifications related to JBoss Application Server. I've developed a project which is compiled in Java 6. And it is deployed in Jboss 5 version. Till now I didn't find any problem with the application. But I want to know will there be any possibility that Jboss will have any backward compatibility problem. Or does Jboss needed upgradation with respect to Java version. Any suggestion would be appreciable.

Thanks,
Marshal.

Comment: @Thomas: Don't really see how it relates to his question?

Comment: @Marshal: You can see on JBoss download page that for JBoss 5 they offer specifically one which is compiled with Java 6 - so you should use this if you execute it with Java 6. We do the same in our projects, having one of the latest JDK 6 and still use JBoss 5.1.

Comment: @Geziefer I slightly misread the question and I'll update my comment and convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even if JBoss 5 is compiled with Java 5 there shouldn't be compatibility problems at a language level.

As for the libraries there might be a problem but those that JBoss requires should have been taken care of. This leaves you with core libraries that JBoss might have replaced in its class loader hiearchy and thus might have an older version. In that case you could put those libraries into your application and effectively override the JBoss versions on a per-application basis. We did that with some XML libs (IIRC JAXB was one of them).

As an alternative - as suggested by @Geziefer - use a JBoss 5 version specifically compiled for Java 6.